# Edit folder name in ldap catalog in php

Tags: php, ldap

Using openLDAP PHP, how can one edit folder name in an LDAP catalog?Tried

```
ldap_rename($conn, $_POST['dn'], 'ou=' . $info["ou"], BASE, TRUE);//error false
ldap_modify($conn, $_POST['dn'], $info);Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: Naming violation in ... false
```

Comment: question may be turned into "how to change dn of the entry?"

Comment: ldap_rename($conn, $_POST['dn'], 'ou=' . $info["ou"], BASE, TRUE) works!!